# How to add more past years in jquery calender

Tags: php, jquery, html, calendar

I am using modified(following modified code taken from stackoverflow ) jquery calender but i want to add more past years and unable to select day.. in this calender please help how can i do this ?The modified script used in html file is this :-

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker( {
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            },
            beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            }
        });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
    yearRange: '1700:2050',
```

the year range gives you more years